# How to efficiently calculate user-item preferences of huge number of users and items?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, memory, optimization

My dataset contains about 75000 users and 10000 items, and whether they liked certain items or not (`1` for liked, `0` for not liked). The items can be present multiple times for each user, and the user's responses to each item are independent of that in the previous instances. This is my code to calculate user preferences for the different items:

```
data=csvread(datafile);
M = data; % Saving the original data in this variable to use later

% Arranging users in descending order of 'activity' (i.e., in order of the number of items liked or disliked by the users)
users = unique(data(:,10)); % The 10th column of the dataset contains the users
users(:,2) = histc(data(:,10),unique(data(:,10)));
users = flipdim(sortrows(users,2),1);

for i=1:size(users,1)

    % Finding the number of times the current user liked or disliked the items
    A=M(M(:,10)==users(i,1),2); % The second column of the dataset contains the items
    catA(:,1)=unique(A);
    catA(:,2)=histc(A,unique(A));


    totalA = sum(catA(:,2));
    catA(:,3)=catA(:,2)/totalA; % Calculating the fraction of items users liked

    allCatA(:,1)=unique(M(:,2)); 
    allCatA(:,2)=zeros(size(allCatA,1),1);

    % Calculating the current user's item preferences
    for k=1:size(catA,1)
        for l=1:size(allCatA,1)
            if catA(k,1)==allCatA(l,1)
                allCatA(l,2)=catA(k,3);
            end
        end
    end

    Y(:,i)=allCatA(:,2); % Saving the current user's item preferences in a vector

    clear allCatA; clear catA;
end
```

The `mxn` matrix `Y` contains the preferences of `m` items for `n` users, where `m=10000` and `n=75000` in my case. A sample output showing the first 5 item preferences of the first 5 users is shown below:

```
0.0092308   0   0           0.0098361   0.0068729
0           0   0           0.0065574   0
0           0   0           0           0
0           0   0.016393    0.0065574   0
0.0030769   0   0.016393    0.04918     0
```

But this has 2 huge problems:

1. It takes a huge time to calculate (took almost a day).
2. Memory is not enough to store the `75000x10000` matrix.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: What you could do is create a knn graph of users, and return the user preferences of every user's k nearest neighbours. There are various libraries available for python that I know of. Best is [nmslib](https://github.com/searchivarius/nmslib/tree/master/python_bindings). It will probably return an answer in under a minute (it might take a few minutes to build the index though). That is if you are not strict on using only MATLAB.

Comment: Looks like your matrix is sparse. Use that to your advantage. See [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/sparse-matrices.html) for more info on sparse matrices in Matlab.